# Unable to connect to database ( mySQL) - can't connect using password (yes))

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am learning to work with database (mysql) in a shared java project, my colleage how created the database gave me a username/password/driver to connect to but i get an error.

I tried re-installing mysql. I can open the sql script unconnected in workbench and I tried to connect through IntelliJ and DB Navigator and i still get an error.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

If its an external database (not installed on the same mashine as you are working) check if remote conntections are allowed and which bind-address is used in mysql.cnf

Comment: Can you explain how, I am searching online but it doesn't work?